# fatal error.. when accessing variables from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have been struggling to access label from UITableViewCell in a UITableViewController..

The code for the class reboundShotsCount looks like this:

This class is defined inside the ShotDetail Class which is subclass of UITableViewController.

```
public class reboundShotsCount : UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet public var reboundCountLabel: UILabel!
}
```

The code in ShotDetail

```
 var shots : [Shot] = [Shot]()
    var shot : Shot!
    var comments : [Comment] = [Comment]()
    var previousImageManager : ImageManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Enable GIF decompression
        self.previousImageManager = ImageManager.shared

        let decoder = ImageDecoderComposition(decoders: [AnimatedImageDecoder(), ImageDecoder()])
        let loader = ImageLoader(configuration: ImageLoaderConfiguration(dataLoader: ImageDataLoader(), decoder: decoder), delegate: AnimatedImageLoaderDelegate())
        let cache = AnimatedImageMemoryCache()
        ImageManager.shared = ImageManager(configuration: ImageManagerConfiguration(loader: loader, cache: cache))

        title = shot.title

        let reboundShotCell = reboundShotsCount()
        // the countLabel returns nil
        let countLabel = reboundShotCell.reboundCountLabel
        // The error comes here.
        countLabel.text = "\(shot.reboundCount)"


        let api = DribbleObjectHandler()
        api.loadComments(shot.commentsUrl, completion: didLoadComments)
        api.loadShots(shot.reboundUrl, completion: didLoadReboundShots)
      }
```

i am aware that the code creates a new instance of reboundShotsCount in viewDidLoad..
 And if i define shot variable inside the reboundShotsCount class. it return's nil.

I am stuck and dont know what to do?

Comment: set text in cellForRowAtIndexPath dataSource method of tableview....in viewDidLoad tableview has not loaded yet and neither tableviewcell

Comment: Thanks!!!! It worked @swiftBUTCHER

Answer (score 0):

You need to set text in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` dataSource method of `tableview`....What you did is in  `viewDidLoad` and at that point `tableview` has not loaded yet and neither `tableviewcell` –